# Fast element wise multiplication of golang integer arrays

Tags: arrays, go

If I have to golang arrays of the same size, Is there a faster way to perform an element wise multiply than a for loop?

It looks like [mat64 element wise multiplication](https://godoc.org/github.com/gonum/matrix/mat64#Dense.MulElem) has some optimizations for contiguous memory, but this is only for 64 bit floating point data.

A trivial example of the for loop is below

```
package main

import "fmt"

const size = 386

func main() {
    var a, b, c [size]int

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        a[i] = i % 16
        b[i] = i
    }

    for i := 0; i < size; i++ {
        c[i] = a[i] * b[i]
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", c[:20])
}
```

Comment: You could have multiple goroutines with each working on a portion of the arrays, but you won't see any performance advantage with that unless the arrays are pretty large.

Comment: you can use the mat64 element wise multiplication and then go over the array and make an int from each element